# How do you say that two timeline "converges"?

Tags: word-request, idiomatic-language

The life of King A "converges" with the life of King B such that King A dies a little after King B is born. How do you say that the lives converges?

> His lifetime ____ with his grand son's lifetime.

Comment: I think you'd say that "their lives overlap" or "their lifespans overlap".

Comment: One thing _converges_ (singular) with another thing. Two things _converge_ (plural).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

King A's life **overlapped** his grandson's.

King A **was alive when** his grandson was born.

King A **lived until** his grandson was [age].

In mathematics we would say: King A's life **intersected** his grandson's life.